# Drawing circles in circles with recursion using turtle module

Tags: python, recursion, geometry, turtle-graphics

There is a task  to draw a circle, draw 6 more circles in it, and to draw 6 more in every one of them... et cetera, like that:

[image].

It should be made using python turtle and recursion methods.

Have no idea where I should ever start. I know, how does turtle work, but recursion is a stumbling block for me. Can someone explain the algorithm? Thanks!

Comment: Notice that every of the six "subfigures" inside the big circle looks exactly like the whole figure. This remark can become a recursive algorithm: in order to draw the figure, begin by drawing a big circle, and then draw six subfigures.

Comment: Note in order to draw the figure you probably need parameters: a center, a radius, and maybe a "depth", ie maybe you don't want to draw an infinite number of circles, so you should specify to which depth you're ready to descend.

Comment: The depth is something like 6^0 + 6^1 + 6^2 = 1 + 6 + 36 = 43 (the number of circles required to make the main circle, 6 in it and 6 in every one of them

Comment: Center of the inner circle is at (R-r1), whereas the inner inner circle center stays at (R-r1-r2), R - main circle's radius, r1 - inner circle's radius, r2 - inner inner circle's radius

Comment: Please don't ask for the solution without any attempt. See [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [find a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/). If you don't understand recursion, start with simpler examples, then build up to the larger problem. If you get stuck on a simpler problem, you can then show an attempt so the question is on topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts about getting started.  You need to determine the diameter reduction from one iteration to the next.  You can use geometry, or since it looks like one circle in the ring might fit in the center, that gives you an estimate.  You need to figure out the angle along the circumference of the outer circle each inner circle appears.  (Simple division.)

You can implement this with a mix of iteration and recursion.  You can iteratively move around the outside of the circle with turtle's `circle()` method, using its `extent` argument to stop along the way, recursively drawing inner circles. With this approach it's a 5 line function with another half dozen lines of support code outside the function to set everything in motion.

Using pure recursion is trickier, in that we need to use the recursion to *both* draw the inner circles and move our way around the outer circle.  Surprisingly, this function can be written with only 6 short lines of code -- they just require more careful thought about what has to be done and in what order.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Since you are asking about an algorithm, I'll just post pseudo-code.

```
def circles(outer_x, outer_y, outer_radius, depth):
    draw outer circle centered at outer_x, outer_y
    # End recursion when depth is 0
    if depth == 0:
        return
    inner_radius = calculate inner circles' radius
    for c in range(6):
        inner_x, inner_y = calculate center for inner circle #c
        # Recursion happens here.
        circles(inner_x, inner_y, inner_radius, depth - 1)
```

Note that Turtle does not render a circle from the center point but from the bottom most point. So it will probably be useful to make a function that draws a circle from the center point.

If you want some actual working code, leave a comment and I will try to post something.

Comment: i'll be glad if you manage to show the final code :)

Comment: @AlexSokolov Ha, I guess not. Somebody voted to close my answer. People on SO crack me up. We're theoretically here to help people, but if you attempt to help but don't follow the arcane rules precisely, other users get upset. But of course _all those people_ follow those rules 100% of the time....except when they don't.

Comment: @AlexSokolov Anyhoo, what you need to do is try to come up with a solution on your own. Then, if it doesn't work, post a new question _with your code_. It doesn't matter if it is good or terrible. People get very upset if you haven't made any attempt or don't show your attempt.

Comment: Thank you for an attempt! I'll definitely try to solve the task using bit of your code

Comment: @001 "we're theoretically here to help people", yes, but only those that have provided an attempt and asked a specific, on-topic question about that attempt. The overall goal isn't to provide a free homework completion service, it's to curate a high-quality Q&A resource for programming questions. This isn't a programming question, it's an assignment dump, so answering it just encourages more low-quality posts and makes it harder to delete off-topic questions. I mean, OP straight up asked you to just [give them the finished code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288133)...